# Why the size of the analysis array needs to be half of the fftSize aka frequencyBinCount

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Trying to make sense of WebAudioAPI's spec.

What is the reason that we are using the `frequencyBinCount` and not the `fftSize` for the size of the analysis array when getting the frequency data?

And should we use `frequencyBinCount` or the `fftSize` for the size of the array when getting the time domain data?

And the last question. In the spec, it is mentioned that if we pass a larger sized array than the frequencyBinCount the excess elements will be ignored, but what if you pass it a smaller array?

So:

```
var analyser = new context.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 1024;

//should fft.size be used? 
//or frequency.binCount
//what happens if the size is smaller than fftSize?
var timeArray = new Float32Array(analyser.fftSize);

//why are we using frequencyBinCount and not fftSize?
var freqArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqArray);
analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(timeArray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that, generally, an FFT of size N will give you N frequency bins. When you're analyzing "real" signals, though, half of these bins will be redundant. Specifically, the first half of the FFT will mirror the second half: bins [2..(N/2)+1] will equal bins [N..(N/2)+1]. Since all audio signals are "real", this symmetry property will hold for any FFT you do in the Web Audio API.  The result will only contain N/2 unique values.

In other words, the analysis array has size N/2 because that's the size of the result. A larger array would be wasteful.

A more rigorous discussion of FFT symmetry is here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/why-is-the-fft-mirrored

Comment: Note that the value in bin 1 is an exception. It isn't redundant, and isn't mirrored anywhere in the FFT result. This is why my indices start at 2 rather than 1.